# viewing profile image from google plus sign in Uri to imageview

Tags: android, android-studio, imageview, uri, google-plus-signin

i know that using

> Uri personPhoto = acct.getPhotoUrl()

will bring the profile image but i still didn't knoiw how to make it viewable in an imageView,how to use `personPhoto`to get the image

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please take the [tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Then come back and edit your question accordingly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use Picasso Library to show images in ImageView.
You just need to pass the uri to Picasso with image view.

like

```
Picasso.with(this).load(personPhoto).into(/*yourimage view id*/);
```

To use the picasso you need to add the following in Gradle

```
compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
```

Read the documentation on http://square.github.io/picasso/

Also There are other libraries to display image in ImageView.
Like [Fresco](https://github.com/facebook/fresco), [Glide](https://github.com/bumptech/glide), [Universal Image Loader](https://github.com/nostra13/Android-Universal-Image-Loader) etc

Answer (score 0):

You have to use Image Loader libraries for loading an image from url and showing them in imageview. Following is the link for libraires that can be used for image loading. [Android Arsenal Image Loaders.](https://android-arsenal.com/tag/46)

I personally use Glide and you can achieve it using it like this.
First add repository in your gradle file like this

```
repositories {
  mavenCentral() 
}
```

And then add following dependencies in your app.gradle

```
compile 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:3.7.0'
```

And to load image do it like this

```
Glide.with(this).load(personPhoto).into(imageView);
```